# Simple math question with LinQ, simple Join query, Nulls, etc

Tags: linq-to-sql, math, join, null, sum

I have 2 tables
  1. Client
  2. Operations

Operations can result in: Credits or Debits ('C' or 'D' in a char field) along with date and ammount fields.

I must calculate the balance for each client's account using linQ... The result should also show balance 0 for clients whom didn't make operations yet

I have the following function with linQ statement, but I know it could be done in a better and quicker, shorter way, right? Which will be?

```
public static double getBalance(ref ClasesDeDatosDataContext xDC, string SSN,
int xidClient)
{
    var cDebits =
        from ops in xDC.Operations
                where (ops.idClient == xidClient) && (ops.OperationCode == 'D')
                select ops.Ammount;
    var cCredits =
                from ops in xDC.Operations
                where (ops.idClient == xidClient) && (ops.OperationCode == 'C')
                select ops.Ammount;
    return (double)(cCredits.Sum() - cDebits.Sum());
}
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the LINQ-to-SQL engine can handle the expression, but something like this should be possible:

```
return (
  from ops in xDC.Operations
  where ops.idClient == xidClient
  select ops.operationCode == 'C' ? ops.Amount : -ops.Amount
).Sum(a => a);
```

Or perhaps:

```
return (
  from ops in xDC.Operations
  where ops.idClient == xidClient
  select new { Sign = ops.operationCode == 'C' ? 1.0 : -1.0, Amount = ops.Amount }
).Sum(o => o.Sign * o.Amount);
```

If the collection is empty, the Sum method returns zero, so that takes care of clients without transactions.

Edit:
Corrected spelling in query: Ampont -> Amount

Comment: I'm getting a runtime Exception... The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: With which of them? Can the Amount field be null? Can there be other operations than 'C' or 'D'?

Comment: Hi Guffa... check the screenshot. This is the exception at runtime (some msgs are in spanish)... http://img130.imageshack.us/i/sshot1s.jpg/

Comment: I did set up some test objects and tried the query, and it works fine. It seems like you have a null value in your data. Does the Amount field allow null values, and does it have any?